# Fastest way to show the content of a text file in a listbox

Tags: file, text, listbox, loading, show

What is the fastest way to load and show a large text file (+/- 50.000 lines) content in a listbox?

I am using: listBox1.DataSource = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);

Is there another control that can load such large files faster then a listbox (with the possibility to select lines)?

Is it the best way to do File.ReadAllLines(filePath) in another thread or backgroundworker?

Thank you in advance!

**Update 2:**
If the application is loading the file, the GUI freezes. 
It does not matter if I load the file in a different thread. How to solve this problem?

Comment: do you intend to do this in windows forms or asp.net?

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Forms RichTextBox control can display a plain-text, Unicode plain-text, or Rich-Text-Format (RTF) file. To do so, call the LoadFile method. You can also use the LoadFile method to load data from a stream. For more information, see LoadFile(Stream, RichTextBoxStreamType).

To load a file into the RichTextBox control

```
private void btnOpenFile_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   if(openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
   {
     richTextBox1.LoadFile(openFileDialog1.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
   }
}
```

The above example utlizies the rich text box control for windows forms. If you need an examle for the web, I could show that as well.